# How to run again that cronjob when the same job finished

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job that runs every 20 minutes from 9-5. Here is the code:

> */20 09-05 * * *

I want it set so that if the job ends in 10 minutes, it starts again automatically. When the scheduled time exceeds 20 minutes, the next job runs when the first is finished. It is a python server running on an Ubuntu operating system.
According to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*):

> // * * * * *  // It runs after every minute

So, if anyone have any solution, please reply me.

Comment: This is not a constant time, so at this point I'd just make a service to execute it in a loop, with custom checks whether to execute or wait.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/